# Python TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una interfaz grafica pero al querer poner un gif de fondo me aparece esto, ya estuve haciendo varias pruebas pero el error persiste

```
  File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\temporal.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
    frames = [Image(file='079.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(79)]

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("SCP-079")

root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("079.ico")
root.geometry("540x360")


frames = [Image(file='079.gif',format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(79)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind>78: #With this condition it will play gif infinitely
        ind = 0
    gif.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)

gif = root.Label
gif.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

###############################################################

Comment: `PIL.Image` es, en efecto, un módulo. Sustituye su importación por `from PIL.Image import Image`.

Comment: Ahora me aparece un error en la misma linea pero con la palabra file
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

Comment: No estas usando correctamente el modulo PIL. Image no acepta argumentos. Para abrir una imagen, tienes que usar Image.open. Te recomiendo qie le heches una leida a la documentación de PIL para que entiendas como funciona: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html